# Displaying each and every value on x-axis in Zing chart

Tags: zingchart

I have many values on x-axis and I want all the values to be displayed on the x-axis when I zoom. Is there any way to do it? As every square has no value mentioned at the bottom, so it would get difficult for the person, seeing the graph, to know which date and time that portion belongs to. You can view my graph on alnnovative.com/zing5.php and could give any suggestion too, if you think it is better to implement, in order to achieve the requirement

Comment: ZingChart team member here -- When we try and view your graph, the page appears to be blank. Can you please update your code and let us know when its visible on the page? Thank you.

Comment: You can view it , it's working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a combination of the numeric `max-items` & the boolean `items-overlap` attributes within your `scale-x` object to find the best way to display the information to your users. In [this demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/UO868MY5), I've reconfigured the format of the timestamps, rotated them to allow for more space, and set the previously mentioned attributes like so:

```
"items-overlap":true,
"max-items":20
```

I hope this helps! I'm on the ZingChart team as well, so please let me know if you have any other questions.